# Correct way to bind delegate to DependencyProperty?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have the following UserControl, trying to accept a user provided `Validation` function. The code "seems" to be fine, Designer did not complaint, compiled fine, and the application ran.. but the callback never triggers. Could some expert point out what else I a missing?

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    [Category("Behavior")]
    public delegate bool FlowValidationEvent(FlowStep currentStep);
    public partial class FlowStep : UserControl
    {   
        public event FlowValidationEvent Validation;
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValidationProperty = 
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                nameof(Validation),
                typeof(FlowValidationEvent),
                typeof(FlowStep),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null)
            );

        public bool Validate()
        {
            if (Validation!= null)
                return Validation.Invoke(this);
            return true;
        }

        public FlowStep()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

At the consumer control level, I created a dummy validation function and passed it over via XAML:

```
public bool Step1_Validation(FlowStep currentStep)
{
    Log.Debug("CALL ME BABE!");
}
```

It was even able to see it and even suggested in the XAML designer, so I think at the `DependencyProperty` level, it seems fine (XAML designer understood it)?

[image]

When starting up, I inspect the element and unsurprisingly, the `Validation` property is not even showing up in my object...

[image]

When I actually triggers the "Next" button and tries to call the `Validate` function, the `event` is `null`...

[image]

Comment: You may want to declare a [routed event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/events/how-to-create-a-custom-routed-event?view=netdesktop-7.0).

Comment: @Clemens Is there such thing like "reverse" routed event? I don't think `RoutedEvent` is what I need, I want to pass a callback and `Invoke` it.

I tried `RoutedEvent` and it was able to trigger the callback, however, it looks like there isn't anything "custom" with the routed event...? It seems super rigid, I can't even change the handler signature. I need my callback to return a boolean to signal whether my validation is successful or failed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was over complicated things. For `event`, I don't need to register it as a `DependencyProperty` and simple declaration worked. All I need was the following and the rest of my code worked as expected:

```
public event FlowValidationEvent Validation;
```

One thing to note is that, despite having an event property `Validation` declared in my class, we still won't see it in the constructor at runtime (weird).